# Can you access the req object in the cy.route method before returning the stubbed data?

Tags: cypress

I am looking to get the req object in the cypress route method. By doing so I could decide what the user gets back when hitting the graphql route which has dynamic responses. Has anyone be able to accomplished this?

I think having access to this would be incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, where `xhr.requestBody` does help in accessing the request body,

```js
cy.route("GET", "/login").as("getLogin");
cy.get("#contactID").type("email@gmail.com");
cy.contains("Login").click();
cy.wait("@getLogin").then(function(xhr) {
  // we can now access the low level xhr
  // that contains the request body,
  // response body, status, etc
  const request = xhr.requestBody;
  expect(response[0]).to.have.property("SomeKey", "Data");
  const response = xhr.responseBody;
  expect(response[0]).to.have.property("LineName", "Line A");
});
```